# Wordpress Plugin into index.php

Tags: wordpress, web

i have a wordpress plugin into "mywebsite.com/wordpress/page1" and i want to , add the wordpress plugin, to my default site "mywebsite.com". Is this possible? adding a wordpress plugin to a common php file? Thanks :D

Comment: what? i did not understand

Answer (score 0):

The OP wants to use a wordpress plugin on a non-wordpress page. While technically possible, you would have to do a LOT of work to make it function, as good plugins rely heavily on wordpress actions and hooks to execute plugin code at certain appropriate times.

A hack, but something that might work, would be to create a wordpress page that uses the plugin in the manner you want, and just place an iframe to it on your non-wordpress page. Again...this is a hack.